# Adding data from a multi-dimensional list to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2 dimensional list called `DataList`.  An example of this list is below:

```
[['Worsheet', 'Field', '', '', 'All Fields', 'Field code', 'Import Sheet', 'Import Column', 'Import Row'], ['Timeliness', 'Requests', '', '', 'Requests', 'A', '1. Timeliness', 'B', '3'], ['Timeliness', '', 'EIRs', '', 'EIRs', 'Ai', '1. Timeliness', 'B', '5'], ['Outcomes', '', 'Granted in full', '', 'Granted in full', 'B', '2. Outcomes', 'B', '7'], ['Exemptions', '', 'S22', '', 'S22', 'S22', '3. Exemptions, exceptions', 'B', '9'], ['Exemptions', '', 'S22A', '', 'S22A', 'S22A', '3. Exemptions, exceptions', 'B', '10'], ['Section 23', '', 'Over 20 days', '', 'Over 20 days', 'Aii', '4. Section 5', 'B', '7']]
```

How can I copy the 5th element of each sublist into a new dataframe, so the expected output would look like:

```
        All Fields
0         Requests
1             EIRs
2  Granted in full
3              S22
4             S22A
5     Over 20 days
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame([i[4] for i in DataList])` ?

Comment: Seems complicated for a simple column fetch. Every nth element in the nested array refers to a column. Looping defeats the purpose of using pandas. Check out the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score 0):

Dataframes are 2D tabular data structures, with rows and columns. 
You want a particular columnar data. This is basic dataframe creation and column fetch. Refer pandas DataFrame [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe:

```py
data=[['Worsheet', 'Field', '', '', 'All Fields', 'Field code', 'Import Sheet', 'Import Column', 'Import Row'], ['Timeliness', 'Requests', '', '', 'Requests', 'A', '1. Timeliness', 'B', '3'], ['Timeliness', '', 'EIRs', '', 'EIRs', 'Ai', '1. Timeliness', 'B', '5'], ['Outcomes', '', 'Granted in full', '', 'Granted in full', 'B', '2. Outcomes', 'B', '7'], ['Exemptions', '', 'S22', '', 'S22', 'S22', '3. Exemptions, exceptions', 'B', '9'], ['Exemptions', '', 'S22A', '', 'S22A', 'S22A', '3. Exemptions, exceptions', 'B', '10'], ['Section 23', '', 'Over 20 days', '', 'Over 20 days', 'Aii', '4. Section 5', 'B', '7']]

df=pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]).iloc[:, 4].to_frame()
```

Outputs:

```py
        All Fields
0         Requests
1             EIRs
2  Granted in full
3              S22
4             S22A
5     Over 20 days
```